# Cryptic stickers, possible riddle?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, cipher

I have found [these very weird stickers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2rU0.jpg) around my town. I followed a trail of these and found around 30 of them. They look handmade and are in different sizes, some roughly cut. The text is flipped vertically on each one and there are no vowels used.

There are four different versions I could find:

- `TRCTWLTHFRTLSLTMLF` ([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9UFO.jpg))
- `MHLTHSGRTNDBNDNT` ([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Lh11.jpg))
- `GDTHNGSNLFCMTMLTHTM` ([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y06Hg.jpg))
- `GNMRNDMRWSDMNDWRNSS` ([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hew3X.jpg))

I have tried a few decoders but I have discovered nothing of significance.

I have also tried merging the mirrored text but I can't figure out if it would resemble another alphabet (i.e. greek).

Any ideas about what this could be?

Comment: I agree with Bass. "My health is great and ...", "Good things ...". I haven't attempted to figure out complete interpretations for these; my prejudices say that "mentally disturbed person" is about as likely as "puzzle hunt".

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I'd say "My health is great and abundant"

Comment: They look handmade, but notably, the mirror-imaged letters are exact mirrors of the regular letters.  You wouldn't get that precise with hand-drawn letters.  This to me seems more like some viral marketing campaign.  (Unless it's just Photoshop...)

Answer (score 6):

Rudimentary letter frequency analysis (no vowels, lots of T,N,S, many familiar consonant pairs like "TH", "NG" and "ND") suggests that they are

> English text with vowels and word spacing removed.

For example, GNMRNDMRWSDMNDWRNSS probably stands for

> i GaiN MoRe aND MoRe WiSDoM aND aWaReNeSS

Here are some guesses for the other ones:

> i a[T]TRaCT WeaLTH & FoRTu[N]e eaSiLy To My LiFe
>  My HeaLTH iS GReaT aND aBuNDaNT (found by Gareth and Thomas Blue)
>  GooD THiNGS iN LiFe CoMe To Me aL[L] THe TiMe (also found by Gareth and Ida)

Given the content, the presentation, and the timing, these might be some variation of the tradition of

> pasting ["Fu"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fu_(character)) stickers [upside down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fu_(character)#/media/File:Xlhhduilian.jpg) on the [Chinese New Year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_New_Year) to attract good fortune.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that...

> "Good things in life come to ..."

Is a potential answer, but I'm not sure how it could end.

Comment: I think "... come to me all the time", but one L is missing.